# Combine vendor javascripts in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vendor

I'm using Angular 2 and I'd like to know how can I combine my vendor javascript files.

for example, I have these files:

- jquery.min.js
- slick.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js

I want to output them as `vendor.js`.

Is it possible do to this?

---

**Edit 1**

In [Laravel](https://www.laravel.com) There's a service called [Elixir](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir), It does exactly what I wish to do with my Angular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grunt / Gulp.
With grunt, you write something like concat:

```
concat: {
    options: {
        stripBanners: true,
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
        '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */'
    },
    js_libs: {
        src: ["jquery.js", "bootstrap.js"],
        dest: 'vendor.js'
    },
}
```

Or if you also want to uglify:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
    },
    js_libs: {
        src: ["jquery.js", "bootstrap.js"],
        dest: 'vendor.min.js'
    }
},
```